# Sharepoint - CQWP and Announcements Body

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I', trying to display the Body property of an Announcements List in my CQWP, but it is always blank.

In `CommonViewFields` I've tried to set Body type to Text, RichHTML, Note... all with no result. Also, as suggested elsewhere. I've tried `disable-output-escaping="yes"` in the xsl. Nothing changed.

Printing out the passed key / values reveals that Body is empty. It should be not.

```
<xsl:for-each select="@*">
    Key:<xsl:value-of select="name()" />
    Value:<xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Generally when you need to output HTML that exists in your data source (or any kind of "result tree"), try invoking the [`xsl:copy-of` element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256183.aspx).

To use your example, it would look like:

```
<xsl:for-each select="@*">
    Key:<xsl:value-of select="name()" />
    Value:<xsl:copy-of select="." />
<xsl:for-each select="@*">
```